# How to override the wordpress default widget markup

Tags: widgets

I am new to wordpress, Here i use the wordpress TwentyEleven theme, i need to customize the widget markup. It means the suppose  i want to change the element 'ul' to div and add some class or id to this element. Now currently it was not possible for me because the wordpress default widgets are already available inside wordpress core file..

Answer (score 6):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget

add something like this to functions.php:

```
if (!function_exists('my_unregister_default_wp_widgets')) {
    function my_unregister_default_wp_widgets() { 
        unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
        unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
    }
    add_action('widgets_init', 'my_unregister_default_wp_widgets', 1);
}
```

Also... you can look at the http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API examples to see how you can extend the WP_Widget class to create custom widgets that you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable all the standard widgets easily by adding an empty text-box widget to the first widget area (see Appearance->Widgets in your admin interface).

But i don't really understand your question, can you specify what you mean? What do you want to show in the widget area?

If you just want to edit the standard widgets in the TwentyEleven theme go to the file: sidebar.php (wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/sidebar.php)

Comment: How can override the default widgets

Comment: Just go to you widget administration page inside you wordpress interface and add an empty text widget to display this empty (invisible) widget instead (or any other widget if you want to display other widgets).

Remember to accept my answer if it helps you solve your problem :)